# How can we restrict the panes based on the selection of Technical Indicators?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am new to HighCharts,Please help me regarding my issue
    In my application I have a dropdown list with lists like:

1. `"Candlestick WITH MA,VOLUME & MACD",`
2. `"Candlestick WITH MA,VOLUME,MACD&SCHOLASTIC OSCILATOR",`
3. `"Candlestick WITH MA,VOLUME,MACD & RSI",`
4. `"Candlestick WITH BOLLINGER BANDS,VOLUME & MACD".`
5. `"Line WITH MA,Volume & MACD",`
6. `"LINE& Volume".`

For the first five indicators it need to show 3 panes and for last "LINE& Volume" it need to show 2 panes only.How can we do this?can we write conditions in highcharts?

Please explain me through small demo...

Comment: Why write conditions in Highcharts? You need to create proper options: one set for 3 panes and one set for 2 panes. Simple demo: `var three_panes = [{}, {}, {}], two_panes: [{}, {}];` Where `{}` is of course options for the pane, like height, top etc. Now, when creating chart, simply use: `yAxis: three_panes` or `yAxis: two_panes`. It just depends which dropdown element you have.

Comment: Hi Paweł Fus, i am new to highcharts..Can you explain with demo through jsfeddle..?

Comment: Sure, could you first create a demo with your case?